# ggplot2: aspect.ratio overpowers coord_equal or coord.fixed

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates

I want to receive a square plot with equal coordinates whatever is the shape of the cloud of my data points.

Here is a primitive illustration of my question.

```
xy <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 y = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 2))
gg <- ggplot(xy,aes(x = x, y = y))+
        geom_point()
gg + coord_equal() #now we have square coordinate grid
gg + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) #now the plot is square

# if we use both, aspect.ratio overpowers coord_equal
gg + coord_equal() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Is there any way to have both plot and the coordinate grid squared? Of course, there would be some blank areas in the plot. I don't mind this.

Also, I'd like to know the simplest way to ensure equal labeling on both x and y axes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the plot to be square by manually setting the scale of the axes:

```
gg +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(min(xy$x,xy$y), max(xy$x,xy$y))) +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(xy$x,xy$y), max(xy$x,xy$y))) +
theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice solution. Only, I think, you meant comma instead of plus within min() and max() functions.

Is there any automatic way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I've edited your answer in order to achieve the desired plot.

Comment: Commas and pluses achieve the same result. Setting the aspect ratio squashes axis formatting, but if the scales are the same, the aspect ratio will be 1 anyway

Comment: No. For some reason, if you use pluses rather than commas, the area of the plot becomes bigger. Just check it.
And if you don't add theme(aspect.ratio=1) in the end, the plot would not be square.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to specify the x-lim and y-lim separately:

```
gg + coord_equal() +xlim(c(-6,6)) + ylim(c(-6,6))
```

which you can esaily replace by a function which derives min/and may based on the data (`?extendrange`).

[image]

Comment: True, that is a solution for the primitive example I provided. The thing I didn't mention is that I need a solution that automatically recognize the axis limits from the input data. I need this solution for a custom plotting function based on ggplot.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with extendrange()?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the `theme()` part as you can simply do this within `coord_fixed()`. 
For your example you could do the following:

```
gg <- ggplot(xy,aes(x = x, y = y))+
        geom_point()
gg + coord_fixed(ratio=1,xlim=c(floor(min(xy$x,xy$y)),
                 ceiling(max(xy$x,xy$y))),
                 ylim=c(floor(min(xy$x,xy$y)), ceiling(max(xy$x,xy$y))))
```

by using `ceiling` and `floor` in the x- and y-lims you don't get the problem that your axis limits lie on top of your outer points.